# Set default reminder to "None" in Windows 8.1 Calendar app

Tags: reminder, appointments, windows-8-calendar-app

Almost all appointments I create in the Windows 8.1 Calendar app do not require reminders, but any appointment created in this app has this option set.

So in all those cases I expand the detailed properties of the newly created appointment and set **Reminder** to *None*.

Is there a way to set this option to *None* by default?